# another Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. TIKZ ifthenelse

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I am trying to plot some equating regarding masstransfer in dialyszers (Eq2) and the derivatives (Eq1). It has to be plotted casewise as it tends to x/0 if b=d. This is working fine for other cases as you can see in the picture provided.

With EQ2 i am getting an error `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` that seems not to be linked to my own errors, if i googled right.

Any ideas how i can overcome this?

[image]
Greetings

MWE:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=newest,
       }%compat ist die versionsnummer
       \usepgfplotslibrary{external} %rendert, speichert, laedt und spart so zeit
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \frac{\partial K(QB,QD,KoA)}{\partial QB}= \\ & \begin{cases} \frac{(de^{k/b}(dbe^{k/b}+(k-d)e^{k/d}b-dke^{k/d}))}{(b(de^{k/b}-e^{k/d}b)^2)} &\forall ~QB \neq QD\\\
k^2/(2(d + k)^2)&\forall ~QB= QD\
\end{cases}
\end{split}
\label{e:dkdqb}
\end{equation}
with:
\begin{equation}
K_{Diffusion} =\begin{cases} QB \frac{e^{\frac{koA}{QB}-\frac{KoA}{QD}}-1}{e^{\frac{koA}{QB}- \frac{KoA}{QD}}-\frac{QB}{QD}} 
\quad & \forall \frac{QB}{QD} \neq 1 \\
 \frac{KoA}{\frac{KoA}{QB}+1} 
 \quad & \forall \frac{QB}{QD} = 1\end{cases}\label{e:k}
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
kqb(\b,\d,\k)=ifthenelse(
\b==\d,%
(\k^2/(2(\d+\k)^2)),%
((\d*exp(\k/\b)*(\d*\b*exp(\k/\b)+(\k-\d)*exp(\k/\d)*\b-\d*\k*exp(\k/\d)))/
(\b*(\d*exp(\k/\b)-exp(\k/\d)*\b)^2))
);
kqb2(\b,\d,\k)=((\d*exp(\k/\b)*(\d*\b*exp(\k/\b)+(\k-\d)*exp(\k/\d)*\b-\d*
\k*exp(\k/\d)))/(\b*(\d*exp(\k/\b)-exp(\k/\d)*\b)^2))
);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.475\textwidth,
       height=0.475\textwidth,
%    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$KoA$,
%     zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={100,200,300,400,500},
%        ytick={200,500,1000},
%             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.2cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.75cm,xshift=-.375cm },
%                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%         view={0}{90},
minor tick num=4,
%colormap,
%colorbar=blackwhite
]
\addplot3[
surf, 
domain=500:100,
    domain y=300:1500,    
%        contour gnuplot={
%        number=10,
%        levels={0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
%        labels={true}},
%        thick,
        samples=45,samples y=45,
    ] 
%    {(kk2(x,1000,y))};  
%        {(kqb2(x,1000,y))}; 
             {(kqb(x,1000,y))};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
kk2(\b,\d,\k)=ifthenelse(\b==\d,%
(\d^2/(\d+\k)^2),%
(((\d-\b)^2*exp(\k/\d+\k/\b))/(\b*exp(\k/\d)-\d*exp(\k/\b))^2));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.475\textwidth,
       height=0.475\textwidth,
%    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$KoA$,
%     zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={100,200,300,400,500},
%        ytick={200,500,1000},
%             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.2cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.75cm,xshift=-.375cm },
%                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%         view={0}{90},
minor tick num=4,
%colormap,
%colorbar=blackwhite
]
\addplot3[
surf, 
domain=500:100,
    domain y=300:1500,    
%        contour gnuplot={
%        number=10,
%        levels={0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
%        labels={true}},
%        thick,
        samples=45,samples y=45,
    ] 
    {(kk2(x,1000,y))};  
%        {(kqb(x,1000,y))}; 
%             {(kqb(x,1000,y))};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
kqb2(\b,\d,\k)=((\d*exp(\k/\b)*(\d*\b*exp(\k/\b)+(\k-\d)*exp(\k/\d)*\b-\d*
\k*exp(\k/\d)))/(\b*(\d*exp(\k/\b)-exp(\k/\d)*\b)^2)));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.475\textwidth,
       height=0.475\textwidth,
%    title={nummer1}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$KoA$,
%     zlabel=$\frac{\partial k}{\partial QD}$,
    xtick={100,200,300,400,500},
%        ytick={200,500,1000},
%             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.2cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.75cm,xshift=-.375cm },
%                   ztick={0,0.5,1},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%         view={0}{90},
minor tick num=4,
%colormap,
%colorbar=blackwhite
]
\addplot3[
surf, 
domain=500:100,
    domain y=300:1500,    
%        contour gnuplot={
%        number=10,
%        levels={0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
%        labels={true}},
%        thick,
        samples=45,samples y=45,
    ] 
%    {(kk2(x,1000,y))};  
        {(kqb2(x,1000,y))}; 
%             {(kqb(x,1000,y))};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `pdflatex -shell-escape xxx.tex`, your example works ok.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ i have `shell-escape` as well as `enable-write18` enabled. Still not working

Comment: There is a missing `*` in `kqb(\b,\d,\k)=ifthenelse(\b==\d,(\k^2/(2 <a missing *>(\d+\k)^2)),<else>)`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks, its working now! why did it work in your Environment without the *? should i delete this post since its just a "stupid" mistake?

Comment: I got the same error if not adding that *. I forgot what I changed in my first comment, sorry. No need to delete, but it's better to provide a more "minimal" example next time when you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @muzimuzhi pointed out it was just a missing *

> There is a missing * in kqb(\b,\d,\k)=ifthenelse(\b==\d,(\k^2/(2 (\d+\k)^2)),).